# database schema : how to make dynamic table according to type?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, database-schema

I’m newbie. I’m designing schema of database and I’m stuck at this place.
I have rooms table and one is rooms_Items such that each room has many room_Items.
The problem is that I need different fields in room_items according to room type

**Room**

```
Id  name

1   LG-12FG

2   LG-31FG
```

**Room_item**

```
Id  name    room_id     required field

1   Window    1          mirror/type/size

2   Door      1           type/size/code

3   Wall      1           layer/color

4   Wall      2           layer/color
```

I’m not sure how to do this. Do I need to make new table for each room_item type ?  If I do like this I have to make condition joins later to fetch all the items of room. Please help

Comment: Just from curriosity, will you run an application on top of the database? An application with business logic?

Comment: @olovholm yes i have to make database first and later from some external source i will import data into it

Comment: Why not transpose your design? I know it will be complex to manage. But will be better normalized and you can transpose back using PIVOT(SQL Server) for joining to other tables. At the same time it will also support scalability.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta please guide how to do this ? I want normalize data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred (normalized) solution would be to create a separate table for each item type (table Windows, table Doors,table Walls). This will make selecting data harder since you will have to do multiple joins.

Alternatively you can create single table containing all attributes of your items:

```
item_id, room_id, type   , size, color,  code, type2      , layer
1      ,       1, Window ,  100,  NULL,  NULL, WindowType1, NULL
2      ,       1, Door   ,   90,  NULL,     1, DoorType1  , NULL
3      ,       1, Wall   , NULL,   red,  NULL,        NULL, 2    
3      ,       2, Wall   , NULL, green,  NULL,        NULL, 1
```

Comment: What if user needs more fields later ?

Answer (score 0):

On your place, firstly i've created a table wich contains data of fields like this:

```
Field_name  ID_Item  Value
size        2        '10.0'
color       3        'Black'
......
```

You may use a builder pattern to create your items in the rooms. As example,

```
exec ADD_Black_Door @roomID
```

This code may add an item (Door) to your room and add all required fields in previous table with default values (Color='Black' and so on).

Comment: in this case how can i select all the items with fields of a room ? please guide

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs correctly you should make three tables:

ROOMS

```
room_id | Name (...)
--------------------
```

ITEMS

```
item_id | Name (...)
--------------------
```

ROOMS_ITEMS

```
room_id | item_id
-------------------
```

In the last table map items which belong to the room.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be more comprehensible if you had a table for each of the entities in the room since this is the unit on which you want to make distinctions between data-values.

Since a Door is not a Wall in your case you can make both these separate tables, then you can use room_items as a table in between.

```
Wall
ID | layer | color

Window
ID | Mirror | Type | Size
```

Then in the room, since an item_id can point to several similar ids as each item creates their own incremental ID, you add the item_type which is used to distinguish what type of element you want to look up.

```
Room 
room_id | item_id | item_type
```

Comment: yes i was doing it same but here we have two problems 1) it would be difficult to select all items of room later. I will need condition join 2) What if user add new type ? I will be required to add new table

Comment: 1) Yes, it would make the queries more complex. 

2) If you want to have total flexibility to change and add new types, why not go for a NoSQL solution e.g. the document oriented NodeSQL? With SQL you need to have a predefinied structure, and if you want to add more elements not planned for, I would consider that a rewrite of the code and then it's OK to alter the database schema, in this case you would also only have to add a new table which would not affect the other tables.

Comment: I'm very new at this level and I've given database and im expecting to work on it. please be specific which table you want to add ?

Answer (score 0):

Please, join a table between two table :

```
SELECT RI.id, 
       RI.name, 
       RI.room_id, 
       RI.required field, 
       R.id        AS RoomId, 
       R.name      AS RoomType 
FROM   room_item RI 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN room R 
                    ON R.id = RI.room_id
```

Comment: Please, post your expected output

Comment: I want to make schema first

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.
Create table Room, Room_Item, Item_specification

**room**

room_id | Room_name

**room_item**

item_id | room_id | item_name

**Item_specification**

spec-id | item-id | spec_name